# Unable to drag element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Here is my angularjs directive code

```
    angular.module('test', []).directive('hello', function() {
    return {
        restrict : 'E',
        template : '<div style="position: relative"><img id="mr" class="drag-image" src="http://www.vancouverconventioncentre.com/wp-content/themes/mobile_pack_base/img/about-us-icon.png" style="position: absolute;" /></div>',
        replace: true,
        link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
            jQuery("#mr").on("keydown", function (){
                 $("#mr").draggable();
            });
        }
    };
})
```

And here is the html code

```
    <div ng-app="test">
<hello>
    <img id="marker" src="http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png" style="position: absolute;" />
</hello>
</div>
```

What i'm trying to do is drag an image (jqueryui.com/draggable) using an angular js directive.But its not working.
Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7fMCF/4/)

Comment: is this what you're looking for ?
http://jqueryui.com/draggable/

please be more specific

Comment: sorry i have updated dat.Ya thats what i'm trying to accomplish through angularjs

Comment: you can easily add some friction

Comment: well, i got confused because of the word "angular" i was thinking that you're about so make an "angular dragging", google that for more information. well, i think you dont need angularjs to make a simple dragging , just use the exampl in the link. just make shure you're including Jquery UI extension.

Comment: any reasons for down vote would be appreciated:)

Comment: i did not downvote yout question ;)

Comment: why would you bind draggable to keydown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at

https://github.com/ganarajpr/Angular-UI-Components/blob/master/js/directives.js#L28

which is essentially

```
myApp.directive('drag',function() {
        return function(scope, elm, attrs) {
            elm.draggable({ containment: attrs.drag});
            elm.css({zIndex:2000});
        };
    });
```

Now you can use an attribute level directive on any element and it will become draggable.

For example :

```
<div drag="parent"></div>
```

Seeing your fiddle it looks like you have not included JQuery UI which is probably one of the reason's why your code is not working. Please include Jquery, JQuery UI and Angular libraries before attempting this.

http://jsfiddle.net/7fMCF/5/

Comment: @iBlue I have updated the answer with a working fiddle ( modified yours! ).

Comment: @iBlue Dint get why you were attempting to it inside a keydown handler!

Answer (score 0):

include jQuery and jQuery UI and by adding this function you should be able to drag your image:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#marker" ).draggable();
});
```

if you want the image to only be draggable in a specific area , check out the API reference up there ->
http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/

you can make the parent ( div ? ) element the bounding box.

hope that's what you're looking for.

Comment: well i want the drag feature in angularjs app